# Apache able to execute file outside web server root directory

Tags: php, apache, unix

I have XAMP installed on my mac and I tried running the command - 
`ps axo user,group,comm | grep httpd` to know what user apache is running as. 
I am getting multiple results one for root and others as nobody. So what is apache running as? A root or nobody and why do I get both root and nobody? Is it because httpd started as a root and then became nobody?

The result of `ps axo user,group,comm | grep httpd` I get is -

```
root        20 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/httpd
nobody      -1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/httpd
nobody      -1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/httpd
nobody      -1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/httpd
nobody      -1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/httpd
nobody      -1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/httpd
nobody      -1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/httpd
nobody      -1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/httpd
nobody      -1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/httpd
nobody      -1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/httpd
nobody      -1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/httpd
nobody      -1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/httpd
```

Secondly, when I execute the following script - 
`echo shell_exec('whoami');` (from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509334/finding-out-what-user-apache-is-running-as)
I just get the result as - `nobody`

The reason I want to know the user is because the php engine is actually able to execute a php file(mysql_details.php) that's outside the web server root directory. And this mysql_details.php has following permissions - `rwxr--r--` i.e. just read permission for other and group. So if apache user is nobody then how can it execute mysql_details.php.

Thanks,
Prat.

Comment: The permission issue I can't answer of the top of my head, but I will say that the location of the target executable within the file system is irrelevant, it is permission only that matter here. The fact that the target executable resides outside DocRoot has no bearing on whether PHP can access it unless you apply a [chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot)

Comment: does that mean phpengine can execute any file in the filesystem if it has the executable bit set?

Comment: If PHP can name the file (see chroot link) and the executable bit is set for world, a group that the PHP user belongs to, or owner and the PHP user owns the script, then yes. File system location has no effect on this rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main Apache process is run as root- the other processes are run as nobody.  The only processes that handle requests are those that are run as nobody, so that if anyone tries to access a file that nobody can't access, they'll get an error (whereas root would be able to access the file).

If you need to execute the file, you can do a few things:

1. Have nobody own the file.  This will give nobody full read/write/execute access to the file, while preventing other users from writing or executing the file.
2. Add nobody to a group, and give that group execute access on the file.  Anyone who is in the group would be able to execute the file, but only the owner would be able to write to it (which would not be nobody).
3. Allow anyone to execute the file.  This is probably not a good idea, as any user would be able to execute the contents at varying permission levels.  It'd probably be best to use one of the above two.

Comment: I agree with your analysis. But my question is, the file mysql_details.php had only read permission for others still how come apache is able to execute it considering it is running as a nobody user.

Comment: @Prat It seems all PHP needs is read permissions on a file in order to execute it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010623/unix-permissions-read-vs-execute-php-context Who would have thought?  Since the file's permissions allow anyone to read it, nobody can read the file and execute it.

Comment: @drderp That is because PHP is an interpreted language, and PHP scripts are not executable themselves unless they have a shebang. Much like shell scripts - you can do `sh script.sh` without exec permissions, but you can't do `./script.sh` unless you have them.

Comment: @DaveRandom I know, I spent a few minutes looking it up.