# How to get to root and then execute shell commands in Python3 on Ubuntu?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, bash, shell, ubuntu-18.04

I am running some shell commands with `os.system` that needs to be run as root.

I tried-

```
os.system("sudo su")
os.system("other commands")
```

and also-

```
home_dir = os.system("sudo su")
os.system("other commands")
```

But both the above scripts just become root and then stop executing, so the rest of my commands aren't executed.

I'm running `Python 3.6.9` on an Ubuntu 18.04 VM.

Comment: How do you expect to become *root* by running two sequenced  `.system(..` where every is running in it's own subprocess. ***stop executing***: The `subprocess` is waiting for input the password, but the dialog is not showing.

Comment: @stovfl So what do you suggest I do?

Comment: Actually, when you run `sudo` from terminal, it requires to enter password,  and similar happen there. After `os.system('sudo')` it requires password but you just can't see it.

Comment: If you need sudo for some purpose, you can easily executive py file as root

Comment: @cike4ka Yes, but this program will be executed automatically(be called by a PHP script)

Comment: @woohu1 Consider to delete this question, you need something like [unix-permissions-read-vs-execute-php-context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010623)

Answer (score 1):

The root privileges gained by `sudo` only apply to the command that is run through sudo, and do not raise the privileges of the caller (in this case, your python script). So your first command `os.system("sudo su")` would run an interactive root shell, but after you have exited from that and then your python code does the subsequent call to `os.system("other commands")`, these will run under its ordinary user privileges.

You could run each command one at a time via sudo:

```
os.system("sudo some_command")
os.system("sudo some_other_command")
```

Note that each command will be separately logged by `sudo` in the system log, and that even if there are several commands, `sudo` shouldn't ask for a password more than once within a short time interval.

Or if you need to do a sequence of steps like changing directories that might not be possible in the caller (for example, if the directory is not accessible by the non-root user that is running the python script), then you could do for example:

```
os.system("sudo sh -c 'cd some_dir && some_other_command'")
```

(Just for info, `&&` is similar to `;` but the other command is only run if the `cd` succeeded, so it is safer, although this point relates to shell syntax rather than python.)

If there are a lot of commands, of course you also have the option of just making a separate "helper" shell-script and running the entire script through sudo.

```
os.system("sudo sh /path/to/myscript.sh")
```

Finally to note, if you are running your python script in a non-interactive environment, you may need to tell `sudo` not to prompt for a password, at least for the relevant invoking user and target commands.  For details, do `man sudoers` and look for examples involving `NOPASSWD`.